# Custom wiring a micro camera to a USB

Tags: usb, wiring

I've been looking for a micro camera that has UVC support but since I haven't found any, I decided to investigate combining a micro camera with a USB-to-serial(?) cable.

Using camera A (see below for photos), can I remove its cable and replace it with the cable ending in the white connector in camera B (splicing the wires)?

Of course, this is more of a 'what to watch out for' question - I realise there are no guarantees, but as I have little experience with electronics, I'd like to know if there are plausible problems with this, or if this is even possible.

Camera A
[image: Camera A]

.

Camera B
[image: Camera B]

Comment: A brief search of eBay turns up a couple of USB inspection/endoscope cameras, some of these are only 7mm in diameter. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I need a 90 degree turn for the connector on the camera like Camera A. The endoscopes are not as such which is why I'm surprised that I haven't found any.

Comment: what if you pulled one of those endoscopes apart and just re-routed the wires at 90'? You probably won't find much off-the-shelf stuff that meets your needs so it's worth looking into whether you can customise an existing solution to do what you want it to do

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Might be an idea, although I have no experience with modifying hardware or electronics...

Comment: It's usually a lot easier to start with a working design and fiddle with the layout than to start a new design from scratch. Building a UVC camera from scratch takes a lot of skill in both (SMD) electronics and low level programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot (easily) be done. Your "micro camera" clearly has a composite analog output, which would have to be digitized before it could be passed to a USB port as data.

Furthermore, a "USB-to-serial" cable would not have the required bandwidth to support live video anyway.

Comment: I guess the digitisation is why Camera B has a larger circuit board? Does this sort of thing that I'm looking for exist (or is possible) at all?

Comment: Sure. You can purchase an [analog video to USB adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4UB2973470&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Accessories+-+Video+Card-_-9SIA4UB2973470&gclid=CM_Yr-jFtc8CFQEkhgodLmcDaA&gclsrc=aw.ds) off-the-shelf.

Comment: Would the resulting combination be UVC-compatible?

Comment: UVC = USB Video Class. I don't see how it would be anything else.

Comment: I've taken a look at analog-USB adapters but out of the ones that were mentioned it, it said that it was not UVC...